# Having trouble removing a user from a department in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a user that is in a department that I can pull the department with the following line

```
    $UserDepartment = Get-ADUser $UserName -Property Department | Select-Object Department
    Write-Host $UserDepartment
```

which returns:
@{Department=SALES}

I need a way to take the user out of the department while not deleting the user and wasn't sure how to go about it

Comment: You mean, clearing the user's `Department` attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear a user's attribute you should use the `-Clear` parameter.

See the [**Parameters** section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#parameters) for this cmdlet.

```
Set-ADUser $user -Clear Department
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
Get-ADUser $UserName | Set-ADUser -Department “”
```

If you wish to mearly clear the department property

You can check out the [powershell documentation for it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#example-8-get-a-user-and-set-a-property)

Comment: I get an error on the line that just says replace